# How do you structure imports for testing inside a module of your project?

Tags: testing, go, module, package

I am attempting to understand how to structure a go project into sub modules stored in separate source code repositories (on host `example.com`), however when I do, I am not sure how to run the tests that are within a module. What am doing wrong in the following example, any help is much appreciated!!

```bash
mkdir -p src/example.com/john/tool

echo "package tool"       >> src/example.com/john/tool/book.go
echo ""                   >> src/example.com/john/tool/book.go
echo "type Book struct {" >> src/example.com/john/tool/book.go
echo "  Title string"     >> src/example.com/john/tool/book.go
echo "}"                  >> src/example.com/john/tool/book.go
echo ""                   >> src/example.com/john/tool/book.go

echo "package tool"       >> src/example.com/john/tool/book_test.go
echo ""                   >> src/example.com/john/tool/book_test.go
echo "import ("           >> src/example.com/john/tool/book_test.go
echo "  \"tool\""         >> src/example.com/john/tool/book_test.go
echo "  \"testing\""      >> src/example.com/john/tool/book_test.go
echo ")"                  >> src/example.com/john/tool/book_test.go
echo ""                   >> src/example.com/john/tool/book_test.go
echo "func TestBook(t *testing.T) { }" >> src/example.com/john/tool/book_test.go
echo ""                   >> src/example.com/john/tool/book_test.go

export GOPATH=`pwd`

go test example.com/john/tool
```

When I run this test, this is the error I am seeing:

```
# example.com/john/tool
src/example.com/john/tool/book_test.go:4:3: cannot find package "tool" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/tool (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/john/app/src/tool (from $GOPATH)
FAIL    example.com/john/tool [setup failed]
```

Obviously `book_test.go` can't import the "tool" package, an you could probably put in the full path, but when I look in github, no one does that in their modules. So I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why are you importing package "tool" again from _test.go file? That is not needed and that is creating the problem as it is looking for some other "tool" package. book_test.go is already part of the tool package you are creating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line

```
import "tool"
```

is the offender. There is no package tool in the standard library and your package tool has an import path of `example.com/john/tool`.

Just drop that import. There is no need to import the current package (and it is impossible as this would be a (degenerated) import cycle).